# Can "language agnostic compilers" exist?

Tags: scala, compilation

The following (strange) code is part of a valid Scala program:

```
/*
  simple-lang s0.3.35
*/
block main()
For a = 0 to 50 {
  display("Hello World at "+a+" ")
}
// end of simple-lang-like program
```

Allthough this code-block is part of the source code of a Scala program, it differs only 3 characters from a [program in another language](https://simple-lang.sourceforge.io/).

I somehow feel it's powerful if a language can treat source code of other (unrelated) languages as source code of its own.

[LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) is a kind of language agnostic compiler, but it "preprocesses" source files of another language by compiling them to an intermediate language.

Can compilers exist that don't preprocess files to an intermediate state?

---

I would like to ask more questions, but they are speculative. Such as, "Will we have such compilers soon" and "Is Scala the first step towards such a compiler".

This is my first Scala program, so bear with me. The only purpose of this program is to show that code that looks strange for Scala can still be parsed without errors.

```
object HelloWorld {

  class Block {
    def main() {}
  }

  val block = new Block()

  class ForClass() {
    var a: Range = 0 to 0;
  }

  val For = new ForClass()

  implicit def removeBody(int: Int) = (body: Unit) => int

  class A() {
    override def toString(): String = "<a>"
  };
  val a = new A()

  var toPrint: Option[String] = None

  def display(s: String) {
    toPrint = Some(s)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    /*
      simple-lang s0.3.35
    */
    block main()
    For a = 0 to 50 {
      display("Hello World at " + a + " ")
    }
    // end of simple-lang-like program
    println(For.a)
    println(toPrint.getOrElse())
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the answers and downvotes it seems my question is misunderstood. I'm not sure how I can express the idea behind this question better.

Answer (score 1):

> Can compilers exist that don't preprocess files to an intermediate state?

Yes, such a compiler could exist. A compiler converts human-readable text into machine-readable instructions, and there is no requirement that it goes through an intermediate form. However decades of research into compilers have shown that having an intermediate form makes compilation easier and produces better code.

> Can “language agnostic compilers” exist?

No, this can't be done, in the same way that a "language-agnostic translator" cannot exist for human languages.

The first problem is that different languages have different *syntax* so you don't know how the words and symbols can be put together to make valid statements.

The second problem is that different languages have different *semantics* so you don't know what the words and symbols mean. For example, there is a `for` statement in Scala and a `for` statement in C, but what they actually do is very different.

And in case you are tempted to invent a new language is compatible with all other languages, here is the [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/) [warning about standards](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: The idea that I have about the semantics is that "for" could be a method that could be overridden in your scala program before the scala program reaches the "C-part". For the syntax you need to be able to ovverride things like the meaning of every symbol. So just like in my example, it's allowed that there is code before "language-specific" code, as long as you can "ctrl-click  in the specific code until you reach the part before it". Note that "0 to 50" is normally not allowed to be follow by a "{", but I hacked that around. Scala is already flexible and it wasn't even meant for this purpose.

Comment: @Albert If you're structuring your program in a certain way to work in multiple languages, it's not the compiler that's language-agnostic, it's the code. This is called a polyglot. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't write a compiler for multiple languages. For example, what should this program do?

```
foo = print "Hello, World!"
```

In Haskell, it compiles, but does nothing, whereas in Python 2, it prints output. The compiler can't know what language to pick, since it is valid in both languages.

However, you can write a program that does the same thing in multiple languages. This is called a [polyglot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)). Here is our above program modified to be a Haskell and Python 2 polyglot:

```
main = print "Hello, World!"
```

As for writing code that looks "strange" like the code in your example in Scala, that's called an internal [DSL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and is actually not uncommon.